# Hachana l'tzorech hatzibbur

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, tefillah-betzibbur, hachana-prep-for-weekday

There is a Rabbinic prohibition of preparing (*hachana*) on *Shabbath* or *Yom* *Tov* for after *Shabbath* or *Yom Tov*. This is the reason why we customarily do not clear after *seudah shlishith* (unless the table/room will still be used before the end of *Shabbath*; see *Shemirath Shabbath Kehilchatha* [SSK] 28:79 cited [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hachana); see also SSK 28:81). This prohibition applies even with regard to preparing for a *mitzvah* (see e.g. SSK 28:69).

What if the *hachana* is also *l'tzorech hatzibbur* - for communal benefit? (For example, say a *minyan* for *maariv* will be held in the home immediately after Shabbath - would one be allowed to tidy the room and set up chairs even though he knows the room will not be used again before nightfall?)

Comment: It'll still be Tosefet Shabbat

Comment: @DoubleAA That's technically just an example. But interesting point nonetheless. Do you have a source for your claim there that until ata chonantanu is considered shabbos re hachana? (There you just cite a gemara about davening on Shabbos, which could be easily interpreted as before nightfall and have nothing to do with tosefet shabbos.)

Comment: Not easily interpreted. Must be interpreted. That Gemara is talking about Maariv after Plag. If Maariv can be recited on Shabbat, then it clearly doesn't effect an end to Shabbat. If it doesn't end Shabbat, then it's still just [Tosefet] Shabbat.

Comment: @DoubleAA You don't happen to have a source for Tosefet Shabbat being unconditionally open-ended like that (i.e. without a time limit). Also, what if e.g. all the mispallelim drive to the minyan and say ata chonantanu first?

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. The other question is about preparing during the _tosefes_ period. This one is about preparing any time, such as before sunset.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure that your tosefet shabbos kula is so pashut. In the SSK, in a footnote, he cites the biur halacha that even bein hashemashos is an issue. It seems pretty dochek to say he means where he said havdala mibeod yom. and there he cited RSZ as meikil within b"h itself, implying after would be an issue...(?)